# When Tildens Reagent is added to an alkene does the product change to an oxime always?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I was reading about Tildens Reagent when I came across this..
[image]

Does this happen always?
Or is it when there is only a single hydrogen attached to the carbon?

Comment: No, this will happen when the starting material is a terminal alkene giving two hydrogens on the carbon, an aldoxime will be formed.

Comment: So the inter conversion happens only when there is 2 hydrogens r8?

Comment: And why is it unstable when hydrogen is present?

Comment: The interconversion will take place whenever there is at least one hydrogen present

Comment: But you told in the beginning that it will happen when the starting material is a terminal alkene giving 2 hydrogens?

Comment: You misunderstand. The reaction will occur will any sibstrate where there is a hydrogen on the carbon, only tertiary compounds will not give this reaction